# Calculation of Parity in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, spinors, parity, dirac-matrices

In the book "Relativistic Quantum Mechanics An Introduction To Relativistic Quantum Fields" by Luciano Maiani Omar Benhar, page 174, the picture of that page is provided below.

I don't understand how 12.9 will give 12.10 by the indicated substitution of 12.7.

I tried rewriting 12.9 into $\bar\phi\gamma^0P^+\gamma^0\gamma^uP\phi$ and could give 12.10, which is,
$$
p\bar\phi\gamma^u\phi p = (P\phi)^+\gamma^0\gamma^u(P\phi),---by(12.7)
$$
$$
=\phi^+\gamma^0\gamma^0P^+\gamma^0\gamma^uP\phi
$$
$$
= \bar\phi\gamma^0P^+\gamma^0\gamma^uP\phi
$$
With this rewriting, i can give for $u=0$ with 12.8 together,

$$
\gamma^0P^+\gamma^0\gamma^0P=g^{00}
\gamma^0
$$
$$
\gamma^0P^+P=\gamma^0=>P^+P=I
$$

I believe the book would not be wrong, so i must miss something.
Could someone please help me out? Thank you^^

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your computation is correct and the book has a typo in 12.9; it misses a $\gamma^0$ between $\bar\psi$ and $P^\dagger$.

Books on physics at this level and up often contain lots of typos of this kind, so you need to watch out. You need to read not just what is written but what the author wanted to write.

Another point is that it's sometimes easier to read textbooks whose errata are available online. For example, Peskin-Schoeder is so well-read that even extremely minor typos have been reported and corrected as seen in [this errata page](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/%7Empeskin/QFT.html).

Comment: Thank you very much @@.  I will try to learn how to understand what the author want to write.